# Metric on real line

Tags: metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and fix some $x_{0}\in X$. Show that the function $f(x) = d(x_{0},x)$ is Lipschitz continuous?

My problem wasn't with solving the question originally I did that using the triangle inequality and showing $\lvert f(x) - f(y)\rvert\le d(x,y)$, but the definition for Lipschitz continuity is $d_Y(f(x),f(y))\le K d_X(x,y)$ where $K > 0$, why can we assume that $d_Y$ is the the euclidean metric?

Comment: It's implicit in the problem: $f:X\to\mathbb R$, is a real function, so it is natural to use the standard metric on $\mathbb R$, which is $d_{\text{Eucl}}(a,b)=|a-b|$.

Answer (score 2):

It is always the metric of your image space you need to look at. And since there was no other metric on $\mathbb{R}$ given, which is apparently the image space of $f$, one implicitly means the standard metric, i.e. the Euclidean one.

Comment: And then we just take $K=1$ as well.

Comment: Yeah, but I thought he/she already got that.